# How to find the boundaries of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $a(n)=\frac{-1}{n!}$ , how does one find the numerical boundaries of this sequence , rigurously ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequence is monotonic increasing: for all n, (n+1)! > n! so 1/(n+1)! < 1/n!, and therefore -1/(n+1)! > -1/n!.

That being so, a(0) must be minimum value = -1.

As n tends to $\infty$ -1/n! tends to 0 from below.

So, -1 <= a(n) < 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough? Obviously 
$$\frac{-1}{n!} < c,\text{ where } c > 0,  c \in \mathbb{R}.$$
The zero comes from 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-1}{n!} = 0.
$$
For the lower boundary firstly $a(1) = \frac{-1}{1} = -1 $. Now consider
$$
a(n) = \frac{-1}{n!} < \frac{-1}{(n+1)!} = a(n+1).
$$

So boundaries are
$$ b < a(n) < c,$$
where $b < -1, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c > 0,  c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How is a(n)>a(n+1) ? For n=2 , is -1/4>-1/6 ?

Comment: Sory, my bad I did not consider the signs. You are right.

Comment: No problem , these things just happen from time to time , no matter how skilled you are .

Comment: That is true. Now the approach should be ok.